# android NullPointer Exception error Custom List View

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im pretty new to android, so by referring to tutorials i came with an application. Im trying to query data from DB and display it in a custom list view. But its throwing me a NUllPointer Exception and im not able to debug it, Pls help me out. Posting the code snippets.
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button add, delete;
ListView lv;
DataHandler enter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

    //opening DB 
    enter.open();
    showList();
    enter.close();      

}

private void showList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   

          ArrayList<MenuListItems> MenuList  = new ArrayList<MenuListItems>();
         // MenuList.clear();        

          Cursor c1 = enter.getAllRows();
          if (c1 != null) {
           if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MenuListItems menuListItems = new MenuListItems();

             menuListItems.setSlno(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("_id")));
             menuListItems.setTitle(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("title")));
           menuListItems.setNote(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("note")));
           menuListItems.setPhone(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("phone_number")));
             MenuList.add(menuListItems);

            } while (c1.moveToNext());
           }
          }
          c1.close();

          MenuListAdapter menuListAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainActivity.this, MenuList);
          lv.setAdapter(menuListAdapter);        

}

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btn_add :
        Intent next = new Intent("com.testing.callreminder.ADDITEM");
        startActivity(next);

        break;    

    }

}}

List Adapter class (custom )

    public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<MenuListItems> menuList;

    public MenuListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MenuListItems> list){
        c=context;
        menuList=list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return menuList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return menuList.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuListItems menuListItems = menuList.get(position);

          if (convertView == null) {
               LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, parent, false);

              }
              TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
              title.setText(menuListItems.getTitle());
              TextView phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvpnumber);
              phone.setText(menuListItems.getPhone());

              return convertView;
    }

}
```

MenuList.Java

```
package com.testing.callreminder;

public class MenuListItems {

     String _id;
     String title;
     String note;
     String phone_number;

     public String getSlno() {
      return _id;
     }

     public void setSlno(String id) {
      this._id = id;
     }

     public String getTitle() {
      return title;
     }

     public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
     }

     public String getNote() {
      return note;
     }

     public void setNote(String note) {
      this.note = note;
     }

     public String getPhone() {
          return phone_number;
         }

     public void setPhone(String number) {
          this.phone_number = number;
         }
}
```

list.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvnumber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Title :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Phone :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvpnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvtitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Listview in mainactivity.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/custombar" >

</ListView>
```

Logcat
 `

```
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614): Process: com.testing.callreminder, PID: 6614
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testing.callreminder/com.testing.callreminder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at com.testing.callreminder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     ... 11 more
```

`

I know its too long, but i dont know where im going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Your Logcat is too small. Indeed I see a `NullPointerException`, but I don't see its trace, which is the sole purpose of the stacktrace. Post it fully please.

Comment: edited! posted the entire log cat

Comment: Problem is in file `MainActivity.java`, line `34`. Show that line on your code (as a code comment for example by editing your post).

Comment: `and im not able to debug it` Why not?

Comment: @PavanKumar `menuListItems.setSlno(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("_id")));` is this your `line 34`, if not could you please highlight it ?

Comment: HI @Outofmemory line 34 is showList(); function call.
enter.open
//Line 34 showList();
enter.close();

Comment: @PavanKumar your source file must have changed since the stack trace was generated, line 34 in the trace above can't be the function call because that function isn't part of the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this block in `onCreate`

```
//opening DB 
enter.open();
showList();
enter.close();
```

You never initialize the `DataHandler` instance `enter`.

That's the cause of your NPE

For future reference, a pretty simple debugging exercise is reading the stack trace to find out where your program is failing.

For example, reading the trace you posted:

```
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at com.testing.callreminder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)  <--- right here is the line that's throwing the exception
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
12-22 22:01:41.353: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     ... 11 more
```

You can see from the second line, the class, method, and line number that is throwing the exception. That would be an excellent place to start looking when you are running into a problem.

Comment: i initialized, but same result :(
enter = new DataHandler(this); was the change i made.

Comment: @PavanKumar no problem. You can now use your stack trace to further figure out why your program is failing, even after trying to initialize your handler.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I debugged successfully and the app is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with line 34. You are trying to use `enter` which is only declare: `DataHandler enter;`, but you forgot to initialise it.